# How would I make this text appear on one line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, string-formatting

I have [this](http://capyspool.co.uk/home/test.html) webpage. [Here](http://pastebin.com/d5zv4rTT) is the raw HTML page.

```
<body>
        <p>GBN: <div id="output"></div>KH/s</p>
</body>
```

My problem is that the words are on different lines. How would I make it so that the worlds 'GBN:', '0' and 'KH/s' appear all on the same line?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not clicking on random links. Put your code *here*, in your question, otherwise when you solve your problem this entire question becomes immediately meaningless and nonsensical to future users.

Comment: Stack Overflow etiquette requires that you include your relevant code here, in the question itself, not in an offsite link.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know this. I will keep it in mind for next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using a `<div id="output">` you could use `<span id="output">` which is inherently inline.

Alternatively you could style the `<div>` with `#output { display: inline-block;}`.

Answer (score 6):

Use  `<span>`  instead of  `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

Use a span instead of a div

```
<body>
    <p>GBN: <span id="output"></span>KH/s</p>
</body>
```